# Avoiding magic-number boosts in ElasticSearch queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, magic-numbers

I'd like documents resulting from an ElasticSearch query that have a field (call it 'fubar') set to certain values that are determined at query-time to always come before documents that don't have fubar set to one of those values.

As an example, at query time I decide that documents with fubar set to 1, 5, or 10 should come before all other documents.

Right now I'm doing this by using the function_score to filter on the fubar being "in" a list of values, and setting the boost to 10x for the filter. The query score and this boosted filter are then summed.

This feels like a hack -- how do I know for certain that a 100x boost won't be needed?  Is there a "clean" way of doing this that doesn't make assumptions about the maximum possible document score? In other words, is there a way to do this that avoids 'magic' boost numbers?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but can you not do it by sorting on that field?

Comment: If you mean sorting after the fact then that wouldn't work because you'd have to iterate over potentially millions of records.  If you mean having elastic-search sort by the field first, then please tell me how to do it!

Comment: Sloan, you were correct -- as I stated the question it could be addressed by sorting.  I've restarted the question -- is sorting still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:** Modified the query sort to match OP's clarified question.

```
{
  "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
  "sort" : [
    {"_script" : {
      "script" : "[1, 10, 15].contains(doc['fubar'].value.toInteger()) ? 1 : 0",
      "type" : "number",
      "order" : "desc"
    }},
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

This sort relies on the specified script to dynamically ascertain whether `fubar` in each document equals 1, 10, or 15 sort sort accordingly.  In this example here I chose to map the result to a 1 or 0, but I'm sure there's any number of other ways you could go about it.  Using the following sample data:

```
{"name":"Alice", "fubar":1}
{"name":"Bob", "fubar":21}
{"name":"Carol", "fubar":33}
{"name":"David", "fubar":17}
{"name":"Evelyn", "fubar":5}
{"name":"Fred", "fubar":10}
```

I got the following result (extraneous bits truncated for readability):

```
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 1, "name": "Alice"},
  "sort" : [ 1.0, 1.0 ]
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "6",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 10, "name": "Fred"},
  "sort" : [ 1.0, 1.0 ]
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "4",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 17, "name": "David"},
  "sort" : [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "5",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 5, "name": "Evelyn"},
  "sort" : [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 21, "name": "Bob"},
  "sort" : [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"fubar": 33, "name": "Carol"},
  "sort" : [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
} ]
```

Note that Alice and Fred get returned first, which is the desired behavior.  For my trivial case all documents have a score of 1.0, so using `_score` as the secondary sort criterion had no effect, but real-world data (with real-world scoring) will take that into account.

Comment: rchang: apologies, I mis-stated the question.  I've edited the question to be what I had intended to ask.  Your answer would no longer work, right?

Comment: @DanSandberg Understood - I have updated the answer, which hopefully addresses your clarified requirements.

Comment: Can I sort by the text query score (the normal _score) after sorting by the script?  If so then you've answered my question and I'm much obliged.

Comment: @DanSandberg Yes indeed you can - the `sort` parameter can be an array that sequentially enumerates the sorting criteria.  See yet another update to the above.  :)